# Number of items limited to around 100

Tags: sapui5

I've created the following Input field.

```js
var oCityInput = new Input({ // sap/m/Input
  showSuggestion: true,
  showTableSuggestionValueHelp: true,
  suggestionItems:{
    path: "/cities",
    template: new ListItem({ // sap/ui/core/ListItem
      text: "{cname}",
      additionalText: "{provi}"
    }),
  },
});
```

The "cities" array contains around 8400 record, but when I type some character the suggestion function it seems that is looking for only in the first 100 items of the array.

I've created an [example in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/saparer/edit?js,output). If you try to looking for the first elements it works... but if you try to type the last city the suggestion will not come out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of SAP UI5 the JSONModel also supports the `setSizeLimit()` method:

```
model.setSizeLimit(iNumOfYourJsonEntries);
```

API description: *"Set the maximum number of entries which are used for list bindings."*

Be careful because it can lead to performance issues.