# Not able to bind complete array list to combo box in UI5

Tags: arrays, combobox, sapui5

I need to bind JSON model to Combobox items.

Created JSON model object

```
oODataJSONModel.setData({
        country: 
JSON.parse(oData2.results[0].Response)
                    });
```

oODataJSONModel object looks like below.

```
country:
BaseObject.Pager:
@firstRecord: "1"
@pageSize: "2147483647"
@searchToken: "SVR1.19V5L"
@type: "ns2:BaseObject.Pager"
item: Array(200)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
length: 200
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Objec
```

You can see item:Array(200)having two array items like [0..99],[100..199]

While binding the above item path to combobox, only first 99 items are displayed in the combobox.

Kindly let me know on how to fill complete list in the combobox.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37193914/5846045

Comment: Btw. seems like you're trying to display list of countries. In that case, you can simply [leverage CLDR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934253/5846045) which comes already with UI5.

Answer (score 1):

The size limit of jsonModel is set to 100 elements as a default. 
If you need more space you can use the function `setSizeLimit` as described in the [docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model%23methods/setSizeLimit)

Remember that with 200 elements maybe the combobox is not the best choice, check if an input with suggestion is more suitable for your use case.